# Sending string from Javascript to Python code using Sockets

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js, sockets

I am new to this area so forgive me if I've not explained myself well enough.

I am trying to set up a basic test where the html page that I've made (served using node.js) connects to my javascript template and that sends a string "hello world" to my python program.

I am connecting to port 3000 and using local host. My python module is capable of binding to the port but doesn't print any data that should be sent to the local host.

I am assuming the issue is oriented around the javascript side. Essentially all I am trying to do is have the webserver send the string as soon as the user clicks the button, although I am not sure how to establish this connection between my js template and html template. Even without a button the js fails to send the data.

I did use src =  and used "alert("hello")" to check that the two templates were linked, which worked; as soon as the user opened the webpage they got a popup statement. But upon trying to send data using sockets, I'm not sure why no data is being sent from the webpage to my python program.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "backendrequest.js"></script>
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick="socketPress();" />

</body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var net = require('net');

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(3000, 'localhost', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello World!');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
    client.destroy(); // kill client after server's response
});`
```

Python:

```
import socket

def Main():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

    # get local machine name
    host = socket.gethostname()                           

    port = 3000

    # connection to hostname on the port.
    s.connect((host, port))                               

    # Receive no more than 1024 bytes
    msg = s.recv()                                     
    
    s.close()
    print (msg.decode('ascii'))
```

**My main objective is to have the user print on python the data, in this case "hello world," coming from my local host, using sockets.**

Any advice would be highly appreciated as I just want to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your javascript code in line 3 and line 7. You haven't closed the brackets. maybe that is the cause.

Comment: unfortunately that isn't the issue. The brackets were large containing functions and were closed on line 6 and 10 using });

Comment: if that is the case then is there a way that you send the msg after connecting to the server ? Because python expects the message to arrive after the client connects. Maybe I am wrong cause I don't know much JavaScript but I think it is worth giving a try.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I'm new to javascript and still trying to get my head around it. What I did do was have the client already listening from the python side (connected to the port); and so when I accessed the webpage, in theory, it should have gotten something. I suspect the issue is related to my javascript code, perhaps I'm not correctly sending it out.